# How can i put value in map from two list

Tags: visualforce, controller, map

i have two list of records,now i want to put them in map,for one list i iterate it in for loop but for second it always get hardcoded. How can i do that,below is my code:-

```
public Map<id,ContentVersion> getContentVersion(set<id> setOfEntityDocId){

    set<id> SetOfDocLink = new Set<id>();
    Map<id,ContentVersion> mapOfCvForDoc = new Map<id,ContentVersion>() ;
    ContentVersion objContentVersion ;
    List<ContentDocumentLink > listOfContentDocumentLink = [Select Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId= :setOfEntityDocId];

    for(ContentDocumentLink cd : listOfContentDocumentLink ){
          SetOfDocLink.add(cd.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    List<ContentVersion> listOfContentVersion = [select id,Title,PathOnClient,ContentDocumentId,FirstPublishLocationId,LastModifiedById,CreatedDate,Category__c   from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId =:SetOfDocLink ];

    List<Entity_Document__c> listOFEntityDocs = [select id,Name,Category__c,Document_Type__c,Expire_Date__c,Language_HRW__c,Description__c,Document_Title__c,Effective_Date__c,Entity__c from Entity_Document__c where id =:setOfEntityDocId];


    if(!listOfContentVersion.isEmpty() && !listOFEntityDocs.isEmpty()){

        for(Entity_Document__c ed : listOFEntityDocs){

            mapOfCvForDoc.put(ed.id, listOfContentVersion[0]);

        }
    }

    return mapOfCvForDoc;

}
```

as i want that i get all the related files in map from the object.i know i hardcoded the list in map..i want to know how can i get rid of that?

Comment: your question is not clear. What are the two list and in which map you want to put? what is the hardcoded list ?

Comment: sorry for inconvinence i have list listOFEntityDocs  and listOfContentVersion and object is entity_Document__c.and i want every entity_Document__c has contentVersion.now when i put it in map  mapOfCvForDoc.put(ed.id, listOfContentVersion[0]); then contentversion is hardcoded

Answer (score 2):

You need to start by considering what is related to what. I think the model is like this (where ^ or v means a reference to the parent):

```
Entity_Document__c
    ^
    ContentDocumentLink
    v
ContentDocument
    ^
    ContentVersion
```

This means that for each `Entity_Document__c` there can be many `ContentDocument` and for each `ContentDocument` there can be many `ContentVersion`.

So this return type doesn't make much sense (assuming the `Id` is of the `Entity_Document__c`):

```
public Map<Id,ContentVersion> getContentVersion(...)
```

unless there are some other constraints applied that e.g. an assumption that there is only ever one `ContentDocument` per `Entity_Document__c` and that you only want say the latest `ContentVersion`.

So best you define the specific logic you require first and then work on the code.

Comment: yes..i got my mistake and will correct it. Thank you @Keith C for suggetion.